# route is listed without mask

Tags: networking, routing

On Ubuntu 18.04 when I list my routes I get the following output:

```
root@ubuntu1804:~# ip route ls
default via 192.168.122.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 192.168.122.236 metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.236 
192.168.122.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.122.236 metric 100
```

I don't understand why the second entry `192.168.122.1` is listed and why it doesn't have a mask. It seems to be the IP of the gateway but this doesn't happen on other distros.
Following is my net configuration:

```
root@ubuntu1804:~# ifconfig 
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.236  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe83:1bdf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:83:1b:df  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 657141  bytes 903750345 (903.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1128  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 161481  bytes 12399386 (12.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8366  bytes 15784491 (15.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8366  bytes 15784491 (15.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


root@ubuntu1804:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens3
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens3
```

In fedora for example, I don't see these routes. The out put I get when listing routes is:

```
[root@myhost ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.16.100.1    0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
172.16.100.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `/32` route (as can be seen in the `route` output which displays `255.255.255.255`, which is a 32-bit mask), in other words, a single host route.

There's nothing special about the route – it's only the `ip route` tool that omits /prefix lengths for host routes (full-length), i.e. it won't show the "/32" for IPv4 and "/128" for IPv6. (This is similar to how it prints "default" instead of "::/0" or "0.0.0.0/0".)

By default, systemd-networkd adds specific routes for the DHCP, DNS, and NTP servers received from that interface (see the `RoutesToDNS=` setting in [systemd.network](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#RoutesToDNS=)). I'm not sure of the reason behind it doing so. It was explained as ["it would make sense"](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11961).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I still don't understand is why I don't see these kind of routes on other distros (I updated my Q with output from Fedora). Is is something that only route cmd of ubuntu shows? could it be omitted by some special flag?

Comment: Well, does Fedora use systemd-networkd as the DHCP client?

Comment: In this case it's using systemd but no dhcp

Comment: I've just checked another Fedora system I have and in fact, when using dhcp I get these kind of routes in the output.

Comment: Didn't ask about systemd in general, the issue is about systemd-networkd specifically.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't get your Q. On Fedora there's no systemd-networkd running but I can see this service running on Ubuntu 18.04.